# Which is the best utility for opening .jpeg, .png and .tiff files on Linux?

Tags: linux, jpeg, png

Which is the most commonly used utility?

Comment: Please change the question to be more specific. Lists and Best Of questions are strongly discouraged on SU. Should the question be more specific it will be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Eye of GNOME](http://projects.gnome.org/eog/) and [gThumb](http://live.gnome.org/gthumb) are among the most popular picture viewers for Linux, partly because they have been included with popular distributions like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s [`display`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php) can not only display images, but also allows you to perform (many) certain ImageMagick operations upon the image being viewed.

Answer (score 2):

[feh](http://feh.finalrewind.org) is light, fast, and powerful.

> feh is an X11 image viewer aimed mostly at console users. Unlike most other viewers, it does not have a fancy GUI, but simply displays images. It is controlled via commandline arguments and configurable key/mouse actions.

Comment: I just tried it, I am sorry but that is one of the worst I have ever tried. A "viewer" that doesn't even scale the image to the window size by default (without giving arguments) is a no go..